# How is rental income taxed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, rental-property

I own two properties which I rent out. I am also paying mortgages on each of these properties (I'm not sure if this matters). How is the rental income taxed? Do I have any options regarding how this is taxed? Any things I should consider?

EDIT:

I live in Seattle, WA, USA.

The homes were purchased in 2003 and 2008.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you just buy them in 2010? If you owned them prior, you might have to amend your returns.

Rental property income and expenses is declared on a [Schedule E](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040se.pdf) and once you add all your expenses along with depreciation, you may show a loss. You can take that loss against ordinary income if your gross income is under a certain level, $100k MAGI begns the phaseout range. Otherwise, it carries over. A gain flows to your 1040 as ordinary income.

I just saw your edit. You bought these 8 and 3 years prior to posting this question. How were you handling your taxes all this time?

Comment: I want to stress *depreciation*. Remember that you MUST depreciate the property according to IRS. If you don't the depreciated value is used when you sell anyway. So take advantage of it.

Comment: You may also be subject to state and local income taxes.

Comment: Do expenses include mortgage payments?

Comment: mortgage **interest** is deductable, same as primary residence.

Comment: Any repairs and improvements are also considered expenses.  Improvements (appliances, a new floor, etc.) also need to be depreciated. Depreciation just means that the expense is taken over time, not all at once.  The length varies from 5 to 30 years, depending on what is being depreciated.

Comment: To clarfify Vitalik's point. mortgage principal payments are not deductible because you didn't actually have an expense. You traded cash for equity, so in theory at least you are net 0 on that transaction.